# Rails Rubber deployment timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-ec2, passenger, rubber

I am trying to deploy an Amazon EC2 instance using rubber. On running 
cap rubber:create_staging I get the following timeout:

```
  * 2014-04-06 20:14:09 executing `rubber:postgresql:setup_apt_sources'
    servers: ["production.foo.com"]
 ** sftp upload #<StringIO:0x0000000420a748> -> /tmp/configure_postgresql_repository
    [production.foo.com] /tmp/configure_postgresql_repository
    [production.foo.com] done
  * sftp upload complete
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l /tmp/configure_postgresql_repository"
    servers: ["production.foo.com"]
    [production.foo.com] executing command
    command finished in 1161ms
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: '  bash -l -c 'apt-get -q update'"
    servers: ["production.foo.com"]
connection failed for: production.foo.com (Timeout::Error: execution expired)
```

I tried increasing the timeout to 60 seconds, but it didn't work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the user you are using to connect with to the instance using Rubber/Capistrano doesn't have `passwordless` sudo access. Try creating the file `/etc/sudoers.d/90-user-you-use-for-rubber` with the following content:

```
user-you-user-for-rubber  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: Well, the 'apt-get -q update' command works before it tries to install the postgresql. In fact, if I make the 'configure_postgresql_repository' file blank, the installation continues but fails at a later point with the same timeout error.

Comment: What is `/tmp/configure_postgresql_repository` doing specifically ?